# SharePoint online, change site title bar to image

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to change the employee service bar into a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to inject custom CSS using SPFX application customizer to add background image in title area.
https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss

Answer (score 0):

For simple customization, you can go settings>change the look to change the Theme and header to do some simple branding like changing color.

[image]

If you want to change it to be a picture, you may need to change the masterpage which is not recommended.